# How to rewrite url for custom domain on Firebase Dynamic Link?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I use Firebase Dynamic Link. I added a custom url link.mydomain.com. Firebase created hosting for this domain.
I can create dynamic link with shortlink like this: link.mydomain.com/abcxyz. It works well.
But I want to rewrite the url so the user can type anywhere they want like this: link.mydomain.com/something-to-show_abcxyz and then link.mydomain.com/abcxyz will execute.

My Firebase project doesn't have any other hosting. I use Firebase CLI but can't get that host to edit firebase.json file.

So I have 2 things stuck:

1. Don't know how to rewrite Firebase Dynamic Shortlink url.
2. Don't know how to connect to the server in my project.